# What value does " sqlDataReader["dbIntegerField"] as String " yield?

Tags: c#, sql

Old Code spelunking here.

The field I'm reading is an integer field in the database (sql server)

it is read in, and for some unknown reason, assigned to a String property in a session object as such:

```
SessionObject.category = reader["category"] as String;
```

The actual values are a bitfield, 0 - 15;

The SessionObject is stored in the session, retrieved later, and all data appears to be present.

At this stage, the category member is converted back to int32 as such:

```
int categories = Convert.ToInt32( SessionObject.category );
```

However, the tests:

```
w.Write(((categories & 1) == 1)? CEhours :0); 
...
w.Write(((categories & 2) == 2)? CEhours :0);
...
w.Write(((categories & 4) == 4)? CEhours :0);
...
w.Write(((categories & 8) == 8)? CEhours :0);
```

all print 0.

Moron Check:

Database values are correct, Condition definitely should be true, CEhours is not 0, query tested fully, etc, etc, etc,

Without any other changes,  I changed the SessionObject field to an int,  Converted to Int32 on reading, and dropped the String to Int conversion in the later code.  Everything worked fine.

So what was wrong with the first way?  (Other than being awkward.)

Comment: For the bitwise `& 1` to equal 1, `categories` would have to be 1 also. Otherwise, it would evaluate to 0 for all other values. This could be further simplified as `categories == 1 ? CEhours : 0`

Comment: Not true.  1111 & 0001 == 1

Comment: Ahh I read it wrong, it's doing even/odd checks. My mistake.

Comment: The problem is that you expect the wrong outcome I think. It should output `CEhours` for all ODD numbers, not even, as it is checking if the least sig digit is set.

Comment: More or less.   It's a common technique for checking if a bit is set or not.  Could use %2 for first bit, but it modulus won't help for higher bits.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `reader["category"] as String` results in null. Try `reader["category"].ToString` instead.

Comment: @DanielCook is right assuming that this is a `SqlDataReader`. I have created an answer combining our commentary.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that.  If I actually tried to do "intvalue as string", I'd get errors.  The fact that it's masked in the Object returned by the SqlDataReader hides it from compile time checking.

Comment: `As` attempts to cast, and upon failure returns `null`. The behavior is documented, but can easily go undetected if you don't know how it works.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore `AS` is a soft cast, which returns `null` if the cast fails rather than throwing an exception. As a result, since it uses `null` to indicate a state of failure, you cannot cast to a value type which does not represent a null state, such as an integer using `AS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer field will arrive in the data reader as a boxed Int32 value. There are basically only two ways of getting the value out, either unboxing it using `(int)reader["category"]` or running the `ToString` method on the value using `reader["category"].ToString()`. The latter naturaly returns it as a string rather than the integer.

When you try to get the value by casting it to a string, you will get a `null` reference back. As you are using the `as` operator it will do as designed and silently fail and return `null` instead of throwing an exception because the casting was not possible.

When you later use `Convert.ToInt32` on the null reference, you will get the value `0`. That is what the method is designed to return for a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielCook has indicated, the line `reader["category"] as String` will return `null` for any value from the database which isn't a `String` itself. It is probably intended that `reader["category"].ToString()` is called instead which will return a string representation of the database value.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore the reason I left the bitwise discussion in is that it seemed the OP was expecting an output of `CEhours` for EVEN numbers, so I was setting them straight on the bitwise logic.

Comment: I am OP.   And it's a simple bitfield check -- 2 is the second bit, 4 is the third bit, 8 is the 4th.  if categories is 9, it should print hours for 8 and 1, but not 4 and 2.

Comment: Edited question to clarify

Comment: NP.  "I" knew what I meant.   Just didn't write it out clearly.

Comment: All good, in hindsight it was powers of 2 so it should have been obvious, but spelling it out certainly helps future readers of this question.